# Why is my application not work and giving me a black screen?

Tags: python, kivy

My application outputs a black screen and doesn't show a grid layout as it should. I hope someone can help me. Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class TheLabApp(App):
pass

class WidgetsExample(GridLayout):
my_text = StringProperty("Hello!")

def on_button_click(self):
    print("Button clicked")


TheLabApp().run()
```

Here is the kivy file:

```
 <WidgetsExample@GridLayout>:
cols: 3
Button:
    text: "Click here"
    on_press: root.on_button_click()
Button:
    text: "Hello"

<PageLayoutExample@PageLayout>:
MainWidget:
BoxLayoutExample:
AnchorLayoutExample:
GridLayoutExample:
```

Comment: *"SyntaxError: expected an indented block"*

Comment: What is the name of your `kv` file?